# How do I change the layout extensions in Jekyll to .liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

By default, Jekyll uses *.html, however, the program I use (Sublime Text 3) has an a package that adds Liquid syntax support but it will only auto detect and do the code suggestions if the file has the extension `*.liquid`. The other problem is, Jekyll is looking for `default.html` as well as the other layouts. How do I make Jekyll look for `*.liquid` files instead like `default.liquid`?

Comment: Instead of changing your layout's extensions, instead change the syntax-highlighting mode in Sublime Text instead like the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom right hand corner of sublime it will have the name of the filetype being used, for example 'HTML'. If you click this you can change it to liquid.

Comment: Yeah but I'd have to do that for every file instead of liquid being automatically detected though

Comment: And I don't want to modify the package to auto-apply to *.html files because that will mess up my other projects that isn't on Jekyll nor uses Liquid. So I'm really looking towards configuring Jekyll to read from the *.liquid instead.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to rename files to `*.liquid.html` and then
update the front-matter to use the new name, e.g.,

### Including `abc.liquid.html` in `default.liquid.html`

```
=== default.liquid.html ===
---
---
{% include file.liquid.html %}
```

### Using layout `default.liquid.html` in a Blog Post

```
---
layout: default.liquid
title:  "My post title"
date:   2021-01-24 19:00
---
```